# \pause and \framebreak in the same frame

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, overlays, pause

I'm trying to use `\pause` and `\framebreak` in the same frame and it does not work.
The reason why I need that is that I'm writing a proof over several slides but don't want the stuff showing up all at once on each slide.

And since it is a proof I cannot just make a new frame instead of using `\framebreak` because of the `\begin{proof}` environment.
Is there any way to do this?

\edit:
Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
\usetheme{Luebeck}  
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{%  
\par
\def\insertproofname{#1{.}}%
\pushQED{\qed}
\alert{\textbf{
{\insertproofname}}} \hspace*{\fill} \\[5pt]}
{\popQED}
\makeatother  

\frame{
\frametitle{(1) Rate function}
\begin{myproof}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item[(i)]
 \vspace*{7pt}
 By definition of $I(\cdot)$ we have 
 \[
   text
 \] 
 \pause
 \[
  ...
 \].
 \end{itemize}
}

\frame{
\frametitle{(1) Rate function}
\begin{itemize}
\item[(ii)]
  ...
 \pause
 \vspace*{10pt}
\item[(iii)] 
...
 \end{itemize}
\end{myproof}
}
```

Where I started a new frame I had `\framebreak` before, but neither of the two ways gives me the desired. I get errors instead.

Comment: Although what you want is not possible, we could suggest you work-arounds. Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **Daniel** mentioned in his answer, it's not possible to use frame breaks and overlay specifications; however, using a `beamercolorbox` (or an appropriate variant, depending on the theme used) you can define a new environment that behaves as the `proof` environment, except for the title, and then you can use this new environment to write the successive parts of your proof in different frames (or in different slides of the same frame).

Below there's an example showing both approaches for the `Berkeley` theme (other themes will require a modification of the box used for the continuation of the proof). Locally redefining `\qedsymbol` you can prevent the symbol from appearing on the first frame/slide and then using `\qed` you can typeset the symbol one the proof is finished:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\setbeamercolor{proofblock}{use=block body,bg=block body.bg}

\newenvironment<>{proofc}[1]
  {\begin{actionenv}#2%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1ex]{proofblock}#1%
  }
  {\end{beamercolorbox}\end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\def\qedsymbol{} % temporarily suppress the \qedsymbol
\frametitle{Proof of the main result}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Proof of the main result (Cont.)}
\begin{proofc}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{proofc}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Proof of the main result (Cont.)}
\begin{proofc}
\lipsum*[4]\qed
\end{proofc}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{
\def\qedsymbol{} % temporarily suppress the \qedsymbol
\frametitle{Proof of the main result}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{proof}
}
\only<2>{
\frametitle{Proof of the main result (Cont.)}
\begin{proofc}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{proofc}
}
\only<3>{
\frametitle{Proof of the main result (Cont.)}
\begin{proofc}
\lipsum*[4]\qed
\end{proofc}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Some images showing the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now that the original question has been edited, the solution is simpler since no block is used in the customized `myproof` environment:

1. Begin and end the `myproof` environment in every frame.
2. Locally redefine `\qedsymbol` for those frames in which the proof isn't yet finished.
3. Use the `myproofc` environment for those frames not needing the title.

A complete example using the code snippet given:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}  
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{%  
  \par\def\insertproofname{#1{.}}%
  \pushQED{\qed}\alert{\textbf{{\insertproofname}}} \hspace*{\fill} \\[5pt]}
  {\popQED}

\newenvironment{myproofc}[1][\proofname]{%  
  \par%
  \pushQED{\qed}}
  {\popQED}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\def\qedsymbol{}
\frametitle{(1) Rate function}
\begin{myproof}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item[(i)]
 \vspace*{7pt}
 By definition of $I(\cdot)$ we have 
 \[
   text
 \] 
 \pause
 \[
  ...
 \].
 \end{itemize}
\end{myproof}
}

\frame{
\frametitle{(1) Rate function}
\begin{myproofc}
\begin{itemize}
\item[(ii)]
  ...
 \pause
 \vspace*{10pt}
\item[(iii)] 
...
 \end{itemize}
\end{myproofc}
} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this!! I don't know if I can figure it out though, since I'm not very experienced with the `beamer` class in latex (and latex in general lol).

Comment: Oh actually I am using another proof environment as the default one, because i did not want it to be in a box but more like normal slide text, here is the code     

`\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{%  
  
  \par  

  \def\insertproofname{#1{.}}%  
  \pushQED{\qed}  
  \alert{\textbf{  
  {\insertproofname}}} \hspace*{\fill} \\[5pt]}  
{\popQED}  
\makeatother`

Comment: @Newby1 OK. I'll provide the code in a few hours; right now I have to rush to a lecture ;-).

Comment: Thank you so much!! And I hope you weren't late to class because of me ;)

Comment: @Newby1 according to your code snippet, you don't need any special redefinitions. If you are not sing a block, then you can simply write your proof in several frames without any further special settings. Or am I missing something? Could you please add your code to the original question (code inside comments doesn't show well) showing all the relevant settings involved (theme that you are using, for example) so I can get a faithful idea about the exact layout?

Comment: I edited my question above.

Comment: @Newby1 please see my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly!!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible :-(

This is clearly stated on page 60 (§8.1) of the [beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) in the documentation of the `allowframebreaks` option:

> - `allowframebreaks=⟨fraction⟩`. When this option is given, the frame will be automatically broken up into several frames if the text does not fit on a single slide. In detail, when this option is given, the following things happen:
>
>   1. **Overlays are not supported.**
>   2. ...

The `\pause` command internally uses `\onslide` (see §9.1 of the beamer manual), so it does employ overlay specifications.

Comment: Mhm, thank you so far, that is really disappointing.  I'm using the Luebeck theme. Is there maybe another way how I could solve this problem? Do you need other information about what I'm using or anything like that?